# How to create firestore timestamp in C# FieldValue.serverTimeStamp()?

Tags: c#, .net-core, webapi

I've tried many other ways I couldn't able to make this happen

```
DateTime.UtcNow()
```

Comment: I've check documentation and there is similar property in C# API ... so where is the problem?

Comment: what's the property you found? which documentation?

Comment: *what's the property you found?* The one which Kumaran wrote in his answer ... *which documentation?* the only one which exists for C# on official firebase docs

Comment: Yes I've miss that Thanks, Selvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install the package

```
Install-Package Google.Cloud.Firestore -Version 2.4.0
```

And Use like

```
FieldValue.ServerTimestamp
```